# In django, is there a way to directly annotate a query with a related object in single query?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, annotate

Consider this query:

```
query = Novel.objects.< ...some filtering... >.annotate(
    latest_chapter_id=Max("volume__chapter__id")
)
```

Actually what I need is to annotate each `Novel` with its latest `Chapter` object, so after this query, I have to execute another query to select actual objects by annotated IDs. IMO this is ugly. Is there a way to combine them into a single query?

Comment: Could you annotate chapters with novels instead?

Comment: Seems not possible to me, because I need only the latest chapter for each novel, but a novel have many chapters, and chapters are in different volumes. As far as I know `distinct()` is useless in this case (correct me if I am wrong), and I don't know any other way to select exactly one chapter except for starting from novel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to combine them into a single query.

You can read the following [blog post](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/) to find two workarounds.

Comment: The answer of rune-kaagaard is better now.

Comment: The linked post suggests using extra() in the query. As of Django 1.8, extra() is not recommended and to be deprecated.

Comment: Now possible with Django 3.2 using JSONObject, see my answer.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, it's possible.

To get a queryset containing all Chapters which are the last in their Novels, simply do:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import F
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

Chapters.objects.annotate(last_chapter_pk=Max('novel__chapter__pk')
    ).filter(pk=F('last_chapter_pk'))
```

Tested on Django 1.7.

Answer (score 14):

Possible with Django 3.2+

Make use of `django.db.models.functions.JSONObject` (added in Django 3.2) to combine multiple fields (in this example, I'm fetching the latest object, however it is possible to fetch any arbitrary object provided that you can get `LIMIT 1)` to yield your object):

```
MainModel.objects.annotate(
    last_object=RelatedModel.objects.filter(mainmodel=OuterRef("pk"))
    .order_by("-date_created")
    .values(
        data=JSONObject(
            id="id", body="body", date_created="date_created"
        )
    )[:1]
)
```

Comment: Oh, I must have totally missed JSONObject - I've just been using my own Func subclass and JsonBuildObject, but I think this is much neater...although sometimes my keys are field values too, rather than fixed keys.

Comment: What if I want to later through django rest api sort or filter using this field?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using Subqueries, docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

```
latest_chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(novel = OuterRef("pk"))\
    .order_by("chapter_order")

novels_with_chapter = Novel.objects.annotate(
    latest_chapter = Subquery(latest_chapters.values("chapter")[:1]))
```

Tested on Django 3.0

The subquery creates a select statement inside the select statement for the novels, then adds this as an annotation. This means you only hit the database once.

I also prefer this to Rune's answer as it actually annotates a Novel object.

Hope this helps, anyone who came looking like much later like I did.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work for me as it seems subqueries can only return a single column and not a complete object.

Comment: @Gnietschow, Yes if you want more than just one column you are probably better off using something like prefetch_related [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me as I want to sort and filter for fields of both models.

Comment: @Gnietschow See my answer that yields multiple columns in a single subquery.