# Annotate with value of latest related in Django 1.8 using conditional annotation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.8

I have the following models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...

class Census(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Now I'd like to annotate a City-queryset with the value of the latest Census. How do I achieve that?

I have tried:

```
City.objects.annotate(population=Max('census__date'))
# --> annotates date and not value

City.objects.annotate(population=Max('census__value'))
# --> annotates highest value, not latest

City.objects.annotate(population=
    Case(
        When(
            census__date=Max('census__date'),
            then='census__value')
        )
    )

# --> annotates 'None'

City.objects.annotate(population=
    Case(
        When(
            census__date=Max('census__date'),
            then='census__value')
        ), output_field=BigIntegerField()
    )

# --> takes forever (not sure what happens at the end, after some minutes I stopped waiting)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Performance matters or is just an offline sporadic report ? 2) Should be database brand agnostic?

Comment: 1) Yes, performance matters, some performance compromise for beauty is acceptable though. 2) Yes, should at least work with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Newer Django versions (>1.8) solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775102/annotate-a-queryset-with-the-latest-value-from-a-filtered-join#43883397

Comment: For Django 3.2+ see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088863/6063532

Answer (score 11):

I've also been having an issue where I need a max value object of a related set, but I require the entire object. I have not been able to figure out a solution using annotation and Case. Until I do, I use this prefetching solution. If each city does not have a large amount of census objects, or if your application is not performance bound, this may work for you.

```
inner_qs = Census.objects.order_by('-date')
cities = City.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("census_set", queryset=inner_qs, to_attr="census_list"))

class City(models.Model):
    @property
    def latest_census(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'census_list') and len(self.census_list) > 0:
            return self.census_list[0]
        return None
```

If this does not work for you, consider some of the suggestions found here:
http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/

Comment: Thanks Mark, that looks like a good workaround. Unfortunately I do have a lot of census objects per city, but maybe I can limit the Prefetch qs like this: inner_qs = Census.objects.order_by('-date')[:1] to still make it efficient. I can't test it right now, but will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, limiting like this doesn't work (fails with "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.") - I will start a bounty and see if someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

At this moment, they are **not a django query expression** to annotate a not aggregated field from a related 1:N model based on a sql having expression.

You can accomplish it with several workarounds like split query and work with data in memory ( itertools groupby f.e. ) or through raw queries. But this will not match your **requirements performance and database agnostic**.

I explain here what I will do if this was my app. For developers is hard to have **redundancy** in database. In your scenario, last `census` by `city` is a calculated field ... but, in this case, **take in consideration to materialize `last_census`**:

*The dirty work ...*

```
class City(models.Model):
    last_census = models.ForeignKey('Census', null=True, 
                                     blank=True, editable=False)
    ...
```

For easy maintenance, you can overrite `save` and `delete` methods on `Census` to keep `last_census` up to date.

```
class Census(models.Model):
    ...

    #overriding save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Census, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        #updating last_census on referenced city
        max_census = Census.objects.filter( city = self.city ).latest('date')
        self.city.last_census = max_census.city if max_census else None
        self.city.save()

    #overriding delete
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #updating last_census on referenced city
        max_census = ( Census.objects
                      .filter( city = self.city )
                      .exclude( id = self.id )
                      .latest('date') )
        self.city.last_census = max_census.city if max_census else None
        self.city.save()
        super(Census, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Notice: if you are more comfortable, you can code it with signals ( pre_delete, post_save, ... ) instead overriding methods.*

*The best ...*

## Your query now:

```
City.objects.select_related('last_census__value').all()
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid race conditions with this solution?

Comment: What you means? Explain. Be free to illustrate with a sample.

Comment: My application will have many users adding and removing 'Census' objects at the same time. I need to make sure this redundant field is accurate, as the users will notice if it is not.

Comment: You should learn about database transactions, [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) and [django transaction control management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work for you:

I have this to show last reservation for restaurants

```
Reservation.objects.filter(
        restaurant__city_id__gt=0
        ).distinct().annotate(city_count=Count(
        'restaurant_id')
        ).order_by('-reservationdate').filter(city_count__gte=1)[:20]
```

in your case it may be something like:

```
city = Census.objects.filter(
        city_id__gt=0
        ).distinct().annotate(city_count=Count(
        'city_id')
        ).order_by('-date').filter(city_count__gte=1)[:20]
```

and your html

```
{% for city in city %}
{{ city.city.name }} {{ city.date }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but it has to be a City QuerySet.

Comment: Thats the trick, you dont actually query the `city` at least not in the `Django ORM` eyes. You query the `Census` and display the `City` name in the results with `{{ census.city.name }}`. The `city` is actually inside your `census` tables as `city_id`. So you query that and display the city name as census.city.name

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Yes, I understood that, but I actually need it to be a City-QuerySet.

Comment: What results are you actually looking for? Just asking because `Django ORM` does the `join` for you and you can display all and any data from the `City` table through the `census` QuerySet. There is no difference ...

Answer (score 2):

It's late and I'm getting hungry so I see won't this all the way through*, but the following code will return the latest census value in a *valueset* for a given city. A queryset might be possible, but again I am hungry!

*I wasn't sure if you needed to retrieve all of the latest values for all cities or a specific city. The latter is pretty easy, the former is a bit harder. You could easily put this as a method on your model and call it on every city in a loop inside of a template/view.

Hope this helps!

```
from app.models import *
from django.db.models import F

    City.objects.annotate(
        values=F("census__value"),
        date=F("census__date"))\
        .values('values', 'name').filter(name="Atlanta")\
        .latest('date')
```