# Django REST Framework Serializers: Display the latest object of a reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The default behavior of the ListAPIView (code below) is to serialize all Report objects and the nested Log objects per Report object. What if I only want the latest Log object to be displayed per Report? How do I go about doing that?

```
# models.py
class Log(models.Model):
    # ...
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class Report(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()


# serializers.py
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Log

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    log_set = LogSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('code', 'description', 'log_set')


# views.py
class ReportListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
```

I know I can do this by using a SerializerMethodField, but this can be a potentially expensive operation, since there will be an extra SQL query to retrieve the appropriate Log object for each Report object.

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latest_log = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Report

    def get_latest_log(self, obj):
        try:
            latest_log = Log.objects.filter(report_id=obj.id).latest('timestamp')
        except Log.DoesNotExist:
            latest_log = None
        return latest_log
```

If I have 1000 report objects, there will be 1000 extra queries if I want to render them all. How do I avoid those extra queries besides using pagination? Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Regarding the possible duplicate tag, the link alone provided by Mark did not completely clear up the picture for me. Todor's answer was more clear.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234880/annotate-with-value-of-latest-related-in-django-1-8-using-conditional-annotation/31237026#31237026

Comment: Hey Mark! I am upvoting your comment and your answer in the link you posted, but I marked Todor's answer as the correct answer, because it is more complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to somehow annotate the `latest_log` in the `ReportQuerySet`, so it can be used by the serializer without making any extra queries.

The simplest way to achieve this is by `prefetching` all the `logs` per `report`. The drawback of this approach is that you load in memory all the `logs` per `report` per page. Which is not so bad if one `report` got something like 5-10-15 `logs`. This will mean that for a page with 50 `reports`, you are gonna load 50*10=500 `logs` which is not a big deal. If there are more `logs` per `report` (lets say 100) then you need to make additional filtering of the `queryset`.

Here is some example code:

1. Prefetch the `logs`.

   ```
   # views.py
   class ReportListView(generics.ListAPIView):

       queryset = Report.objects.all()\
                   .prefetch_related(Prefetch('log_set', 
                       queryset=Log.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp'),
                       to_attr='latest_logs'
                   ))
      serializer_class = ReportSerializer
   ```
2. Create a helper method for easy access the latest_log

   ```
   class Report(models.Model):
       #...

       @property
       def latest_log(self):
           if hasattr(self, 'latest_logs') and len(self.latest_logs) > 0:
               return self.latest_logs[0]
           #you can eventually implement some fallback logic here 
           #to get the latest log with a query if there is no cached latest_logs 
           return None
   ```
3. Finally the serializer just use the property

   ```
   class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       latest_log = serializers.LogSerializer()

       class Meta:
           model = Report
   ```

An example of a more advanced filtering of the `logs` can be something like this:

```
Report.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('log_set', queryset=Log.objects.all().extra(where=[
    "`myapp_log`.`timestamp` = (\
        SELECT max(timestamp) \
        FROM `myapp_log` l2 \
        WHERE l2.report == `myapp_log`.`report`\
    )"]
    ), to_attr='latest_logs'
))
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Learned a new technique today! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [select related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) argument. It will hit the database only once using JOIN.

```
class ReportListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Report.objects.select_related('log');
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
```