# Getting Posts and its last comment in a single queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's assume I've the classic blog `Post` with multiple related `Comment`s model.
I'm trying to get a list of posts each annotated with its last comment
(or at least a single field from it).

The closest I've gotten is via:

```
Post.objects.annotate(last_comment=F('comment__text'))
```

But this just returns the body for the first commend, and I explicitly
want the last.

Am I missing something pretty obvious? Or is there some smart way of
doing this that I'm failing to see?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. Check this related question and decide which works best for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234880/annotate-with-value-of-latest-related-in-django-1-8-using-conditional-annotation/31313003#comment50615846_31313003

Comment: Never tried this - but what happens if you specify the `ordering` meta attribute on the comment model ?

Comment: @MarkGalloway Regrettably, the best solution mentioned there there is keeping a redundant attribute to store the last `Comment`. That's what I'm doing now and would like to avoid.

Comment: @karthikr That *seems* to work, though it sounds a bit like an instance of "programming by coincidence".

Comment: Haha.. No, it is not a coincidence. The only downside is, this ordering is the default everywhere, except for explicit order_by

Comment: @karthikr That won't really be an issue since I *always* want this on my scenario (I'm actually overriding the default queryset with this annotation).
Is there any clear explanation to why the first instance is used though?
Also, you might want to make your comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the latest comment, you might want to specify an [`ordering` on the `Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Something like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   ...
   class Meta:
       ordering = ('-created_at', ) #or id, or whatever
```

Then, your query

```
Post.objects.annotate(last_comment=F('comment__text'))
```

would retrieve the latest post.

Specifying the `ordering` (in this case) is the equivalent of saying `Comments.objects.order_by('-created_at')`, and it would always work, as you want the latest comment.

One caveat here though is, the `ordering` is applied by default *everywhere* the comments are retrieved. Also, has some database implications as the ordering is not free

Comment: Actually, I've now realized that `get()` fails with this, because I seem to be getting N `Post`s, where N is the amount of `Comment`s for that post.

Comment: Looks like this *does* work as expected in all scenarios:
`Post.objects.distinct('id').annotate(last_comment=F('comment__text'))`

Comment: Scrub that last comment, that makes `get` work, but makes `filter` fail with an SQL error.